# MIPS: Clarification on Load/Store word base + offset

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator, mips64

I am currently learning MIPS and would like some clarification on store/load word.

is:

```
sw $t0, 4($s0)
```

the same as

```
addi $s0, $s0, 4 # offsets are in bytes/word 8*4*4
sw   $t0, 0($s0)
```

Additionally, I understand the offsets are 16 bits signed immediates. However, what if it was greater like a 32 bits immediate?

example

```
sw $t0, x($s0) # x is a 32bits offset
```

Comment: (1) I don't see why you converted 4 to 512. (2) The processor doesn't support immediate offsets bigger than 16 bits, so you'll have to come up with some other way, probably by using multiple instructions.

Comment: not exactly the same as with 4($s0) that register is not modified it is simply a base address for a base + offset.  as far as the memory location being addressed, yes they are the same.  the offset is limited in size, see the instruction definition, it cant be remotely 32 bits is probably 16 or less, but I would have to check.  If the instruction set has a register base + register offset addressing mode then you would do that otherwise you have to modify a register or use a second one (or third depending on the offset).

Comment: you did simulate these before asking this question yes?  what did the simulator show with respect to your question?

Answer (score 0):

> what if it was greater like a 32 bits immediate?

Then MIPS instruction words would have to be longer, like 48 bits, to still have room for opcodes and register numbers plus 32-bit immediates.

---

But I think you're asking **what if you had a 32-bit *offset* that was too big to use as an *immediate*?**

The obvious way would be to do all the address calculation yourself, materializing the 32-bit value into a temporary register with `lui`/`addiu` and then using `addu` to calculate the final address in a register.  (Because MIPS doesn't have a reg+reg addressing mode, only `reg+imm16`).  But then we wouldn't be taking advantage of the imm16 in the load at all.

We can do better by using the low part of the offset as the immediate in the load, only using 2 extra instructions instead of 3.  Compilers know this trick so it's easy to show an example:

```
char foo(char *p) {
    return p[0x123456];
}
```

compiles with [MIPS gcc5.4 on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'char+foo(char+*p)+%7B+return+p%5B0x123456%5D%3B%7D%0A%0Achar+arr%5B1024%5D%3B%0Achar+idxarr(int+idx)+%7B+return+arr%5Bidx%5D%3B+%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:45.96238980113961,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips5,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-fno-delayed-branch+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'MIPS+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:54.0376101988604,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) to this asm:

```
# gcc5.4 -O3 -fno-delayed-branch
foo:
        li      $2,1179648              # 0x120000
        addu    $4,$4,$2
        lb      $2,13398($4)            # 0x3456($4)
        j       $31
        nop
```

`$4` is `$a0`, `$2` is `$v0`.  So this is doing `reg += %hi(0x123456)` with lui / addu, then using `%lo(0x123456)` as an offset to that.

A similar trick should be possible if you used a static array and a register index, but that's not what GCC actually does.  Probably because it doesn't know if the low 16 of the static address will have its high bit set or not, so sign-extension creates a possible off-by-one for the upper half of the address.  Maybe there's no relocation type that will account for that and adjust the `%hi()` part according to the high bit of the `%lo()` part, making this optimization impossible :/

I used `char` so C wouldn't scale my index: array index = byte offset because `sizeof(char) = 1`.  `lb` is a sign-extending load into a word register because that's how MIPS's calling convention works for narrow args.